# unable to access custom webpage from mobile device via wifi access point

Tags: ip, wifi, access-point

I have a D-Link WiFi AP (`192.168.1.0/24`), DHCP enabled with default settings. And I have connected my Windows (Windows 10) Laptop with my WiFi AP (`192.168.1.11/24`), my PC connected with AP and got the IP from DHCP as `192.168.1.33`. And I have an android mobile, connected with AP and got IP from DHCP as `192.168.1.34`.

Both (PC and Mobile) default gateway is `192.168.1.11` and connected with AP. Which looks fine and as expected.

I have hosted a small web application in my PC, and working fine from PC's browser by accessing with the IP (`192.168.1.33`), But when I am trying the same from Mobile's browser, i could not access the web page.

I could ping the Mobile IP from my PC. But still I could not access the web page from Mobile.

Am I missing anything.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed an Antivirus program in my PC and then It worked fine. I really don't have idea why it did't work earlier. But, what I have noticed is while I starting up the tomcat instance, firewall(Antivirus) popped up and asking for permission to access port 8080. After that, it was working as expected.